# What is the equivalent of _i64toa_s?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, llvm

I am trying to compile my MSVC++ module using LLVM and I can't find a good alternative for the _i64toa_s function.

Comment: If it does what I think it does, `std::to_string` would be a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

use [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) or [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)